# How to retrieve casted date without toArray or toJson?

Tags: laravel

For formatting some date column via casts, for example:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'deadline' => 'date:d/m/Y',
];
```

when getting column, it'll return carbon instance:

```php
dd($model->deadline);

// Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1671235200 {#1542 ▶}
```

But even when it's casted to string, it won't be formatted as specified in cast:

```php
dd( (string) $model->deadline );

// "2022-12-17 00:00:00"
```

Just when I can get formatted date, that whole model be casted toArray, or toJson,

```php
dd($model->toArray()['deadline']);

// "17/12/2022"
```

So there isn't any easier way to get formatted date without casting whole model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a getter to overwrite your attribute :

```php
public function getDeadlineAttribute()
{
    return $this->deadline->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

If you want all your date formated that way for your model, you can use this :

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Comment: Haha :-) . Im sorry i dont saw your answer. But it is 90% equal. It means that is right. +1Up from me! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your model a new getter function like this:

```php
public function getFormatedDateAttribute()
{
    return $this->deadline->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Comment: you have to add ```>``` after ```$this-```. ```$this->deadline->format('d/m/Y')```  is right